# Category list as a file explore

Tags: magento2, category

I am trying to find example code to create a category list that provides choice of brands with the option to choose underneath as per the below image. I have searched most of the magento forums and I cannot find any examples.

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Which Magento version? Why use catrgories and not layered navigatiom?

Comment: Magento2. I have not looked at layered navigation. I have set up my catalogue (there are over 10,000) items and I need a simple way to navigate all the items.

Comment: I would go with a "brand" attribute and enable layered navigation. This would save you loads of trouble in the long run

Comment: Great - thanks very much indeed for your help.